# Dialogflow does not recognize right intent wifh particle "not"

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have bot for support in Russian language and I have one problem with intents.

Bot has 10 intents, and I want that phrases with word "did not arrive" go to intent FAILED. I have wrote that to training phrases and save intent. But in this situation all phrases with word "arrive" are in intent FAILED too. But this phrases may be in any another intent. I have tried to write training phrase "arrive" in another 9 intents and "did not arrive" only in FAILED intent, but bot stopped understand this word and there was many fallback intents. Can anybody advice the solution of this problem?

Comment: I have found one decision, when I create entity "not_come" with value "did not arrive", dialogflow triggers intent FAILED only when there is all words "did not arrive" in incoming phrase, when in phrase there is only "arrive" it match to fallback intent. but it is very difficult to make entities for all variants of negative incoming phrases, maybe anybody knows another way?